# Running a Custom Show in PowerPoint Using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

I am trying to run a custom show in PowerPoint using VB.net

I have managed to get a list of custom shows using:

```
myPres.SlideShowSettings.NamedSlideShows(intSlideNumber).Name
```

However, I cannot workout how to start a custom show.  When the show finishes, I would like to go back to the slide that was being displayed when the custom show started.

Thanks for any help!

Dave